# How to make window maximum on VirtualBox and how to install KDE on CentOS 8.1?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos, kde

Installed CentOS 8.1 on VirtualBox 6.1.

Have installed Guest Additions(Devices -> Install Guest Additions CD image...) to CentOS, but after reboot, it still can't make maximum size.

The second time I tried to do again, it said

[error picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHgI0.png)

Why?

---

Another, its default desktop environment is gnome, I want to install KDE on it. But tried these ways all failed.

```
sudo yum groupinstall 'KDE' 'X Window System'
Module or Group 'KDE' is not available.
Module or Group 'X Window System' is not available.
Error: Nothing to do.

sudo yum groups install "KDE Plasma Workspaces"
Module or Group 'KDE Plasma Workspaces' is not available.
Error: Nothing to do.
```

Where can I find the official way?

Comment: Limit your post to a single question please.

Comment: You might need to enable epel repo first. Can try `sudo dnf --enablerepo=epel,PowerTools group -y install "KDE Plasma Workspaces" "base-x" `

Comment: @fawildchild I heard CentOS 8 doesn't support KDE.